# Cannot find module '#node-web-compat' from aws-jwt-verify library in Next.js tests

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, next.js, jestjs, jwt

**Issue description**

I'm going to test the service in api used in Next.js app and using babel jest for that specific tests file. The problem that I struggle is issue regarding finding a module and the error that appears in terminal is as in the listing below.

```bash
    Cannot find module '#node-web-compat' from 'node_modules/aws-jwt-verify/dist/cjs/https.js'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/aws-jwt-verify/dist/cjs/https.js
      node_modules/aws-jwt-verify/dist/cjs/jwk.js
      node_modules/aws-jwt-verify/dist/cjs/jwt-rsa.js
      node_modules/aws-jwt-verify/dist/cjs/index.js
      pages/api/auth/auth.service.ts
      __tests__/sign-up/api/auth/auth-service.test.ts

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:491:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-jwt-verify/dist/cjs/https.js:9:28)
```

The tested service is used by TypeScript decorator in middleware. It works as expected when I'm testing it manually but the issue appears only while running tests.

**Goal**

My goal is unit testing service that uses library `aws-jwt-verify` to verify JWT accessToken. I would like to mock it and use in my `jest` unit tests.

**tried methods**

I've tried to copy dependency to `devDependencies` and reinstall packages but it didn't help

**dependencies in package.json**

```json
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.137.0",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.2.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.7",
    "@storyofams/next-api-decorators": "^1.8.2",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.0.10",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.0.10",
    "aws-jwt-verify": "^3.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.34.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "storybook-addon-next-router": "^4.0.0",
    "zod": "^3.17.10"
  },
...
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
 test environment
  dir: './'
});

const customJestConfig = {for alias' to work
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/']
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

**auth.service.ts**

```js
// auth.service.ts
import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from 'aws-jwt-verify';
import { BadRequestException } from '@storyofams/next-api-decorators';
import { CognitoAccessTokenPayload } from 'aws-jwt-verify/jwt-model';

export class AuthService {
  async verifyToken(token: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const verifier = CognitoJwtVerifier.create({
      userPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
      tokenUse: 'access',
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_WEB_CLIENT_ID
    });

    try {
      const verifyResult: CognitoAccessTokenPayload = await verifier.verify(token);

      const isNotExpired = verifyResult.exp > Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      const isCorrectClient = verifyResult.client_id === process.env.COGNITO_WEB_CLIENT_ID;
      const isCorrectUserPool =
        verifyResult.iss ===
        `https://cognito-idp.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}`;
      const isTokenUseValid = verifyResult.token_use === 'access';

      return isNotExpired && isCorrectClient && isCorrectUserPool && isTokenUseValid;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new BadRequestException(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

**auth-service.test.ts**

```js
// auth-service.test.ts
describe('Auth Service', () => {
  describe('verifyToken', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('should verify token successfully', async () => {
      jest.mock('aws-jwt-verify', () => {
        return {
          CognitoJwtVerifier: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
              verify: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
                exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600,
                client_id: process.env.COGNITO_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
                iss: `https://cognito-idp.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}`,
                token_use: 'access'
              })
            };
          })
        };
      });
      const authService = new AuthService();
      const result = await authService.verifyToken('token');
      expect(result).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I figured out that the problem exists in version `3.x.x` based on issue and edit [from here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify/issues/69#issuecomment-1129647365) the error disappeared after downgrading to version `2.1.3` but still I need to properly mock library because `create()` method is undefined here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced this issue using typescript, jest, and ts-jest. For me this gitHub issue provided the answer.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12619

needed to add this to my jest.config

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '#node-web-compat': "./node-web-compat-node.js",
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**issue with mock library**
After trying to downgrade library version to 2.1.3 it helped. I was inspired by [issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify/issues/69#issuecomment-1129647365)

**Issue with mocking**
I decided to use `spyOn`

```js
import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from 'aws-jwt-verify';
...
jest.mock('aws-jwt-verify');

test('my test', () => {
 jest.spyOn(CognitoJwtVerifier, 'create').mockImplementation(() => {
   return {
     verify: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
     exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600,
     client_id: process.env.COGNITO_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
     iss: `https://cognito-idp.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}`,
     token_use: 'access'
       })
     };
  });
})
```